# How do I import an existing project into Aptana 3.04.2?

Tags: import

I installed the Wordpress bundle in Aptana. I'm on a Mac running MAMP. My operating system is Leopard. My project is located at Sites->mysite.

Unfortunately, I'm getting "No projects are found to import" when I try Aptana's import wizard.

1. I clicked "Import Project"
2. Clicked "General"
   3.Selected "Existing Projects into Workspace"
3. Clicked "Next"
4. Select root directory-- browsed to mysite. But, I got "No projects are found to import".

How do I import my project (without messing it up)? Should I use "Create Project" instead? If so, how do I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a slightly different mechanism, since your original project was not an Eclipse-based project:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Importing+an+Existing+Project

Note that the process is made easier in 3.0.5 from the above link.

Comment: Hi @Ingo Muschenetz, Thank you for the message and link. I was able to import my project. Thanks.